# Getting new records from query based on values of older records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query scope that checks which matches have to be add on to the query based on what the current time is.
 Matches will be displayed if the `start_date` from that match is between this Tuesday and the next Tuesday and they also need a `status` field of `SCHEDULED`.

A new set of matches has to be loaded when that matchday comes to an end. This can either be Sunday or Monday. now I noticed that the next matchday will start on november 24th, this means that on Tuesday november 13th, no matches will be add on to the query. Working with times will not be a useful method if I still want the upcoming matches to be displayed the day after the last match has finished.

My goal is to always add the new upcoming matches when all current matches have ended.

**Code**

**Query**

```
 $matches = Match::thisWeekScheduled()->get();
```

**Scope for getting correct matches based on time**

```
public function scopeThisWeekScheduled($query) {
    $start_date = now()->previous(Carbon::TUESDAY);
    $end_date = now()->next(Carbon::TUESDAY);
    return $query->whereDate('date','>', $start_date)->whereDate('date','<', $end_date)->where('status', 'SCHEDULED');
}
```

**Match migration**

```
Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('match_id');
    $table->string('homeTeam');
    $table->string('awayTeam');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->dateTime('date');
    $table->integer('matchday');
    $table->integer('homeScore')->nullable();
    $table->integer('awayScore')->nullable();
});

// last match of this matchday

// match_id  = 233136
// homeTeam  = Arsenal FC
// awayTeam  = Wolverhampton Wanderers FC
// status    = FINISHED
// date      = 2018-11-11 16:30:00
// matchday  = 12
// homeScore = 1
// awayScore = 1

// First upcoming match

// match_id  = 233144
// homeTeam  = Fulham FC
// awayTeam  = Southampton FC
// status    = SCHEDULED
// date      = 2018-11-24 15:00:00
// matchday  = 13
// homeScore = NULL
// awayScore = NULL
```

**Extra information:**

- I have every match of the season in my database. Matches have a
  status of `SCHEDULED` or `FINISHED`.
- Im using a scheduled task that gets the updated match information from an API. Status of the match gets updated when the API has different values.
- A matchday has 10 matches

Any tips on approaching my issue?

Answer (score 0):

`$matches = Match::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14)->toDateTimeString());`

here You can use subDays() has value as you want to show previous days ..i use for 14 days

Comment: This is not what i'm trying to achieve, This will basically load all my matches at once